# How to create a custom SQL query inside my SQLAlchemy model?

Tags: python, sql, flask, sqlalchemy

So I have a model in SQLAlchemy which represents a shop (name, address, latitude, longitude). I need to execute a custom query which allows me to pass in the latitude and longitude of my current location to find nearby shops. I want to be able to call this model method from inside my view to return a set of shop objects. Can anybody advise me on how to implement this functionality into my model?

Answer (score 0):

my solution on same problem

```
sql = "SELECT id, name,(" \
                    "6371 * ACOS( " \
                    "COS( RADIANS( :lat ) ) " \
                    "* COS( RADIANS( latitude ) )" \
                    "* COS( RADIANS( longitude ) - RADIANS( :lng ) )" \
                    "+ SIN( RADIANS( :lat ) ) " \
                    "* SIN( RADIANS( latitude ) ) )) " \
                    "AS distance " \
                    "FROM shop " \
                    "ORDER BY distance"

answer = shop.query.from_statement(sql).params(lat=lat,lng=lng).first()
```